# Customers not listed in Paypal Preapproved Payments page for recurring billing

Tags: paypal, payment, recurring-billing

I inherited a website that was made a long time ago using the Paypal payments pro API to subscribe customers on a recurring billing basis.

One of the users wanted to cancel his account.

I logged into Paypal and went to `Profile > My Money > My Preapproved Payments`, and there is no one listed!

It says:

> "There's no data available"

Since I was not able to cancel his recurring payments in time, he was billed again and I had to refund his payment.

For the life of me, I can't find how to remove him or anyone else from the recurring payments that are being made, and I can't figure out how these payments are going through if they are not listed in the `preapproved payments` page.

I hope I'm not going crazy or something. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The guy who wants to quit needs to go into his own account, and cancel them himself.  I'm not going to go into details where and how, but the merchant doesn't cancel pre-approved payments; the buyer does.

Comment: +1: Paypal's tools for managing stuff like this is a bit.. lacking.  It actually amazes me that with the amount of money they make they can't do a decent UI.

Answer (score 0):

try "my Selling Tools" instead of "My Money"..... the payments under My Money are going out, the payments under Selling Tools are coming in

Comment: Unfortunately, both the My Money and the My Selling Tools version of the preapproved payments pages are empty.